# DrawerLayout in Android with expandable list and header with single scroll

Tags: android

[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

This is my layout I need header also be the scroll with an expandable list. How can I do this?  Please help, I have header layout as another layout also need to hide some data in the header in some condition how I can do it.

Comment: Can you add the image of layout that you want to implement?

Comment: i have added the image where list is scroll but i need header should also scroll not be fixed